# Simultaneous equations in 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$x^2+xy+y^2=c$ $;$
$y^2+yz+z^2=a$ $;$
$z^2+xz+x^2=b$ $;$
$xy+yz+zx=0$ $.$

Find relation between a,b,c(eliminate x,y,z)

I came across this question while i was solving an olympiad book

My approach was to first substitute $x$ from the 4th equation and further eliminate $y,z$ but it was very tough to get the result with this approach

Secondly i got up to these three equations:-

$x^2+y^2+z^2=(a+b+c)/2;$
$(x+y+z)^2=(a+b+c)/2;$
$(x+y)^2+(x+z)^2+(y+z)^2=(a+b+c);$

But i cannot figure out how could we eliminate $x,y,z$ using this approach .hence i was stuck at this point and also tried some more methods like subtracting two equations etc...

It is not a homework problem.

Comment: Use Groebner bases with lex order.

Comment: Your question is quite likely to be closed unless you can describe something about your own thoughts, what you have tried, where you got stuck, and so on. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Are you sure that four equations are given?

Comment: Yes those four equations are given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding up the first $3$ equations,

$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+xy+yz+zx=a+b+c$

So, $2[x^2+y^2+z^2-(xy+yz+zx)]=a+b+c$

Therefore, $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=a+b+c$.

and $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)=\dfrac12(a+b+c)$

Note that $(x-z)(x+y+z)=x^2-z^2+xy-yz=c-a$

$(x-z)^2=\dfrac{(c-a)^2}{(x+y+z)^2}=\dfrac{2(c-a)^2}{a+b+c}$.

Similarly, $(y-x)^2=\dfrac{2(a-b)^2}{a+b+c}$ and $(z-y)^2=\dfrac{2(b-c)^2}{a+b+c}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \dfrac{2(c-a)^2}{a+b+c}+\dfrac{2(a-b)^2}{a+b+c}+\dfrac{2(b-c)^2}{a+b+c}=a+b+c$.

$2[(c-a)^2+(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2]=(a+b+c)^2$

$4(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)=(a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca)$

$3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-6(ab+bc+ca)=0$

$a^2+b^2+c^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=0$

Comment: I cant point out where you wrong but the answer is not the desired one .....

Comment: What is the answer? There are many equivalent forms.

Comment: $A^2+B^2+C^2+3(AB+BC+CA)=0$ where $A= a^2-bc$. $B=b^2-ac$. $C=c^2-ab$

Comment: @AkshajBansal I found a mistake in the first step. Just corrected.

Comment: Ok thnks but please derive the same answer as i mentioned

Comment: @AkshajBansal If $A=a^2-bc$, $B=b^2-ac$ and $C=c^2-ab$, then $A^2+B^2+C^2+3(AB+BC+CA)=(a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((a%5E2-bc)%5E2%2B(b%5E2-ac)%5E2%2B(c%5E2-ab)%5E2%2B3((a%5E2-bc)(b%5E2-ac)%2B(b%5E2-ac)(c%5E2-ab)%2B(c%5E2-ab)(a%5E2-bc)))%2F(a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2-2ab-2bc-2ca)

Comment: Ok I got it but still can you please give a direct method to derive the result that i mentioned (sorry for further arguements ) because the question is from 'pre college mathematics ' (book) and it gives the answer that i mentioned .....so there must be a method to go directly to the answer

Comment: As $A^2+B^2+C^2+3(AB+BC+CA)$ is divisible by $a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca$, my  answer would directly imply that $A^2+B^2+C^2+3(AB+BC+CA)=0$.